# Flutter- User Complete profile after google sign in

Tags: flutter, dart

I am new to flutter, I have a "complete profile" screen after the user signs up with google auth, but I want it to show to the user only once and don't show the screen again if the user has provided details already

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you will save the information that you gathered in the complete profile screen in a firestore document?
In that case, you will just have to check if there is a document in a 'user' collection with the UID that firestore auth provides, if so then display your normal hopme screen of your app, else display the complete profile screen. You can do this easily with a futurebuilder.

Comment: thank you so much I also used FlutterFire documentation to know how to query with future builder